# Problem of starting and stopping the activity indicator

Tags: iphone, ios, uiactivityindicatorview, uiviewanimation

`What I am doing right now`
I am making an application which is uploading the image on the server...it's kind a application where image are shown in the row with send button..and when we press send button..it should be uploaded on the server..

`What I want...`

here I want to use the Activity Indicator..

Now I want that when I press the send button i want to show the indicator..and when the image is uploaded the indicator should be removed

`My Problem...`
I dont know where should i put [spinner startAnimating]; and [spinner startAnimating]; methods..I can't put it in the viewDidload because I don't want it to be shown when application starts..I only want to show the indicator only and only I press the send button.
and I want activity should be stopped when the uploading is finished..

any suggestion??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
- (void)sendButtonPressed {
 [spinner startAnimating];
//code to download
}

- (void)finsihedImageDownload {
[spinner stopAnimating];
}
```